# IBM SBT SDK 1.0.1 (Java): How can I (de)activate Community applications like Blogs or Files?

Tags: java, widget, ibm-sbt

Is it possible to switch off / remove or switch on / add / activate Community widgets like Blogs (not present by default, but addable in IBM Connections UI) or Files (present by default, and removeable in IBM Connections UI) using the IBM SBT SDK?

When I explore the IBM SBT SDK 1.0.1 source code I can only find direct access to members (add/invite, list...), forums & topics, bookmarks, and for files there is upload/download functionality. But I cannot see anything like "addWidget(widgetType)" or "disableWidget(widgetType)" or the like.

When I explore the blog / files package I also cannot see any relation to communities in the source code.

Do I miss something?

How does IC itself achieve building an actual relation community/files or community/blogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Christian, unfortunately, those APIs are not reflected in the Java API.

There is a corresponding set of REST URLs, and you can easily add a method to the extended class which accomplishes this functionality.

The REST Documentation is at

[http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_community_widgets_ic45&content=pdcontent](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_community_widgets_ic45&content=pdcontent)

Comment: Currently this answers my question, but I hope to see improvements on this topic in the SBT some day :-|